# Finding the general equation of a perpendicular line to a given line that passes through a point. (using vector algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, analytic-geometry

How can I find the genral equation of  a perpendicular line to a given line that passes through a point, using vector algebra?

**For example:**

given a line $\ell_1: \begin{bmatrix}a_1 \\ a_2 \end{bmatrix} + t \begin{bmatrix}b_1 - a_1 \\ b_2 - a_2\end{bmatrix}$

and a point $\mathbf{P} = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$

How can you fine the general equation (form: $\;\;a_1x + b_1y + c = 0 \;\;$) of the line $\ell_2$ that passes through $\mathbf{P}$ and perpendicular to $\ell_1$?

Comment: I will appreciate any help!

Comment: The term "vertical to $\ell_1$" is not standard mathematical terminology. Do you mean that $\ell_2$ is *perpendicular* to $\ell_1$?

Comment: Yes, youre right, I meant perpendicular

Comment: @BenGrossmann Do you have an idea?

Comment: The answer will be $(b_1-a_1)x + (b_2 - a_2)y = 0$

Comment: That said, your question is currently written as a problem statement without any other context. Note that askers are expected to provide context for problems, as is [explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Please [edit] your post to say, for instance, where you encountered this problem, what you have tried so far, and any other relevant thoughts you have.

Answer (score 0):

Since the line $\ell_2$ must pass through the origin, it is of the form

$t\left[\begin{matrix}c_1\\
c_2
\end{matrix}\right]$,

for some $c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{R}$.

As $\ell_2 \perp\ell_1$, one ought to have that any vector parallel to second line is orthogonal to any parallel to the first one, that is

$\left[\begin{matrix}t c_1\\
tc_2
\end{matrix}\right]^T\left[\begin{matrix}s(b_1-a_1)\\
s(b_2-a_2)
\end{matrix}\right]=0$

for all $s,t\in\mathbb{R}$. Now, you may take $s=1$ and you get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let the equation of the given line be $\vec{r}= \vec{a} + \lambda \vec{b}$ and the given point be $P \equiv\vec{c}$. Let the perpendicular line meet the given line at $Q$ given as $\vec{a} + \lambda \vec{b}$. Then $\vec{PQ} = \vec{a} + \lambda \vec{b} - \vec{c} $. $\vec{PQ} \cdot \vec{b}=0$. Therefore, $\begin{equation*}
\lambda = \frac{(\vec{c} - \vec{a}) \cdot \vec{b}}{|\vec{b}|^2}
\end{equation*}$

We have the position vector of $Q$ and therefore direction vector of the line $P$, say $\vec{d}$. Then equation of $PQ$ is $\vec{c} + \lambda \vec{d}$

Answer (score 0):

First, find the point **C** on the line which is closest to point **P**.

The line is defined by $L=A+t\,\left(B-A\right)$ where $t$ is an arbitrary scalar value.

The distance (squared) to the target point is $$ d^{2}=\left(P-L\right)\cdot\left(P-L\right)$$

> <sub>Here $\cdot$ denotes the vector dot product $A\cdot B = A_x B_x + A_y B_y $</sub>

Now we find $t$ which sets $\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\left(d^{2}\right)=0$

$$\begin{aligned}d^{2} & =\left(\left(P-A\right)-t\,\left(B-A\right)\right)\cdot\left(\left(P-A\right)-t\,\left(B-A\right)\right)\\
\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\left(d^{2}\right) & =2\left(\left(P-A\right)-t\,\left(B-A\right)\right)\cdot\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\left(\left(P-A\right)-t\,\left(B-A\right)\right)\\
0 & =-2\left(\left(P-A\right)-t\,\left(B-A\right)\right)\cdot\left(B-A\right)\\
0 & =\left(P-A\right)\cdot\left(B-A\right)-t\,\left(B-A\right)\cdot\left(B-A\right)\\
t & =\frac{\left(P-A\right)\cdot\left(B-A\right)}{\left(B-A\right)\cdot\left(B-A\right)}
\end{aligned}$$

And so point **C** is

$$ C=A+\frac{\left(P-A\right)\cdot\left(B-A\right)}{\left(B-A\right)\cdot\left(B-A\right)}\,\left(B-A\right) $$

You can now draw a perpendicular line between **P** and **C**

$$ M = P + u\, \left( C-P \right) $$ where $u$ is an arbitrary value.